# Removing certain characters of a certain file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to remove certain characters from multiple files which share the same extension. An example would be: `filename = 01songname.mp3` to `songname.mp3`, but doing that command to all the mp3 files in the directory, not renaming to one name but removing the numbering.

Comment: You are going to have to be much more specific. From your examples I could deduce that you are either removing numbers from the file name or removing the first two characters from the file name.

Comment: Now that you updated your question. You realize that is a really poor example. You can't rename two files to the same name.  BE MORE SPECIFIC with your descriptions and examples.

Comment: Remove certain characters, in this case 0,1,2 but that can also apply to a space character or a - character

Comment: What @Squashman is saying is that in your example, you would have two files **both** named songname.mp3 in the folder. Windows won't let you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your existing examples this may work for you.

```
@echo off

FOR %%M IN (*.mp3) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%G IN ("%%~M") DO ECHO RENAME "%%~M" "%%~G"
)
pause
```

Remove the word ECHO before the word RENAME if you feel the output on the screen looks correct.